# Quoting and escaping in Maven Exec plugin

Tags: maven

How does quoting and escaping work for parameters passed to Maven plugins?

For example I want to pass multiple filenames as arguments to an application run by the Maven Exec plugin:

`mvnDebug exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="Main" -Dexec.args="/path/to/file1 /path/to/file2"`

But what if the paths have spaces?

I've tried using \":


`-Dexec.args="\"/path/to/a file\" /path/to/file2"`

and "":


`-Dexec.args="""/path/to/a file"" /path/to/file2"`

neither works :-(. Neither does moving the first quote before -D.

The source code for the Maven Exec plugin doesn't help me either, it receives a String[] from somewhere, but where?

Note that I must get this to work from the command line, without changes to the POM file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try single quotes (`'`) but I doubt that will work, either.

The problem is that you can have several `argument` elements inside the POM (hence the array in the plugin's source) but you have only a single property from the command line.

Options:

- Patch the plugin and/or open a feature request to support several arguments (maybe `exec.args.0, exec.args.1, exec.args.2, ...`)
- Create a module which depends on this project/module and where you can change the POM
- Use an Ant or BASH script. I often use this approach to collect useful commands which aren't easily supported by Maven. `mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=...` will give you the classpath in this case.